# If $f$ is nonnegative and measurable then its integral is the limit of integrals of truncated functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> If $f$ is nonnegative and measurable, show that $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-n}^{n} f = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\{f \geq 1/n\}} f$$

So I'm looking at this and this is screaming Monotone Convergence Theorem, but I'm not completely sure how to use it entirely because I don't know how to show $f$ is increasing.

My approach was: let $f$ = $f_n\chi_E$ where $E = [-n, n]$ since $f_n$ is measurable, we have that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N$ such that  $|f - f_n| < \epsilon$ whenever $n \geq N$ which means that $f_n \rightarrow f$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

So $f_n = f$ if $|x| \leq n$ and $f_n = 0$ otherwise.

But this says that $\{f_n\}$ is monotonely decreasing... Is there something wrong with my argument? I don't really know how to get around this.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think $\{f_n\}$ is decreasing.  It's increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_n = f \chi_{E_n}$ where $E_n = [-n,n]$. Then $f_n$ is a sequence of measurable functions. Since $E_1 \subset E_2 \subset E_3 \subset \cdots$, $f_n$ is monotonic increasing. Given $\epsilon > 0$ and $x \in \Bbb R$, choose $N \ge |x|$. If $n \ge N$, then $f_n = f$ and thus $|f - f_n| = 0 < \epsilon$. Consequently, $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$. Now you can deduce from the monotone convergence theorem that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_n  \to \int_{-\infty}^\infty f$, i.e., $\int_{-n}^n f \to \int_{-\infty}^\infty f$. Use a similar argument to show that $\int_{\{f \ge \frac{1}{n}\}} f \to \int_{-\infty}^\infty f$.